# How to get all records as parent records with child records chained together?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to return a set of root records with their children populated within, chained together with their respective children as well.

Here's what I mean,

```
CREATE TABLE animal (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  animal_name VARCHAR(25),
  subanimal BIGINT[]
);

INSERT INTO animal VALUES
    (1, 'Mammal', '{2,3}'),
    (2, 'Person', '{}'),
    (3, 'Dog', '{}'),
    (4, 'Reptile', '{5}'),
    (5, 'Lizard', '{6,7}'),
    (6, 'Gecko', '{}'),
    (7, 'Chameleon', '{}'),
    (8, 'Birds', '{}');
```

How can I get this to return the following:

```
parent_id | animal_name |    subanimal
----------+-------------+-----------------
        1 |    Mammal   | [ { "id": 2, "animal_name": "Person", "subanimals": [] }, { "id": 3, "animal_name": "Dog", "subanimals": [] } ]
        4 |   Reptile   | [ { "id": 5, "animal_name": "Lizard", "subanimals": [ { "id": 6, "animal_name": "Gecko", "subanimals": [] }, { "id": 7, "animal_name": "Chameleon", "subanimals": [] } ] } ]
        8 |     Birds   | []
```

Here's what I've tried,

```
WITH RECURSIVE populated (id, animal_name, subanimal) AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    animal_name,
    ARRAY[]::bigint[]
  FROM animal
  WHERE array_length(subanimal, 1) > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    animal.id,
    animal.animal_name,
    case
      when array_length(animal.subanimal, 1) > 0
        then animal.subanimal
      else populated.subanimal
    end
    FROM animal 
    JOIN populated ON populated.id = any(animal.subanimal)
) SELECT
    c.id as parent_id,
    c.animal_name,
    to_jsonb(c.subanimal) as subanimals
  FROM populated p
JOIN animal c
on p.id = any(c.subanimal)
```

I can't get this to work quite how I need it to, as it neither populates nested records nor actually returns the expected result.

How can I get this to work?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H1z8USjx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would blow out the arrays, calculate a tree, and then recurse upward to build the result:

```
with recursive blowout as (
  select id, animal_name, child_id, 
         (to_jsonb(animal)||'{"subanimals": []}') - 'subanimal' as janimal
    from animal
         left join lateral unnest(subanimal) as s(child_id) on true
), tree as (
  select id, 0 as level, id as root, janimal, animal_name
    from blowout b
   where not exists (select 1 from blowout where child_id = b.id)
  union 
  select c.id, t.level + 1 as level, t.root, c.janimal, c.animal_name
    from tree t
         join blowout p on p.id = t.id
         join blowout c on c.id = p.child_id
), build_order as (
  select id, level, root, animal_name, janimal,
         row_number() over (partition by root 
                                order by level desc, id desc) as rn
    from tree
), rebuild as (
  select id, level, root, animal_name, rn,
         jsonb_build_array(janimal) as janimal
    from build_order 
   where rn = 1
  union all
  select ps.id, ps.level, ps.root, ps.animal_name, ps.rn,
         case
           when ps.level = c.level then ps.janimal || c.janimal
           else jsonb_set(ps.janimal, '{subanimals}', c.janimal)
         end as janimal
    from rebuild c
         join build_order ps on ps.root = c.root and ps.rn = c.rn + 1 
)
select id, animal_name, (janimal->'subanimals') as subanimals
  from rebuild 
 where id = root
 order by id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gVWLnXzW)

Comment: Such a seemingly clever and complicated query for a relatively simple task. Maybe I need use a better table structure or approach?

Comment: @MikeK  The major stumbling block is that aggregating is not allowed in the recursive part of the recursive query.  For this reason, a better approach would be to use a host language or an iterative function.